# How do you assign new atrributes to elements in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html

I was going through a tutorial and came across these lines of code but I dont understand the meaning of the 'data-behavior' and 'data-animation' attributes.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-behavior="editor-message"></a>

<div className='row animated fadeInUp' data-animation='fadeInUp-fadeOutDown'>
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: A link to the tutorial would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These atributes allow you to pass any kind of data in your html tag. They are "homemade" attributes that you can use and access like any other.
You can have some explanation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

Common usages are passing along a url that you will use in javascript in a data-url attribute, or any kind of values, really.

Answer (score 0):

The `data-` attribute is given to HTML elements when we want to provide extra data to them, without breaking the W3C convention and default attributes.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Whilst the `data-*` attributes are really helpful in conventional web development, i.e. developing apps raw and without JavaScript, there are several workarounds in React.JS that will not prove to be a headache.

Please provide extra information